# canDeactivate not returning true in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, observable

Basically I have a canDeactivate guard on a form page, which gets activated when the form if dirty & not submitted, but it is not getting routed when I confirm to route it & also when I submit the form.

I checked the return value in console for confirm & it logs as true but the route stays on the same route.

If someone could help, below is my code for reference.

**With Observables:**

```
  canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
      if (this.heroForm.form.dirty && !this.heroForm._submitted ){
          $('#yourModal').modal('show');         

          document.getElementById("confirm").onclick = ((e: any) => {
              $('#yourModal').modal('hide');
              console.log(true);
              return true;
          });

          document.getElementById("cancel").onclick = ((e: any) => {
              $('#yourModal').modal('hide');
              console.log(false);
              return false;
          });

      } 
      return true;
  }
```

**With Promise:**

```
canDeactivate(): Promise<boolean> {
let $modal = $('#yourModal').modal();
  return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {

        document.getElementById("confirm").onclick = ((e: any) => {
            $('#yourModal').modal('hide');
            resolve(true);
        });

        document.getElementById("cancel").onclick = ((e: any) => {
            $('#yourModal').modal('hide');
            resolve(false);
        });

      $modal.modal("show");
    });  
}
```

**Update.html**

```
  <form (ngSubmit)="saveData(); isClickedOnce = true" #heroForm="ngForm" *ngIf="this.news !== undefined">
  <div class="abcd clearfix">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-6">
      <label for="newsdescription">News Description:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="news_description" name="newsdescription" placeholder="News Description" [(ngModel)]="this.news.newsdescription">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="abcde clearfix">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-6">
            <label for="formData">News Image (Required):</label><span [hidden]="!togglefile" class="alert alert-danger">
                Image is required.
            </span><br>
            <input #fileInput type="file" id="newsimg" name="newsimg" multiple="true" (change)="fileChange($event)" required="true">
    </div>  

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="yourModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Discard unsaved changes ?</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
          <button type="button" id="confirm" class="btn btn-success" title="OK">Yes</button>
          <button type="button" id="cancel" class="btn btn-danger"  title="Cancel">Cancel</button>
        </div>                    
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!heroForm.form.valid || togglefile" [class.disabled]="isClickedOnce" title="Save">Save</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="gotoNewss()" title="Cancel">Cancel</button>
    </div>                    
  </div>  
  </form>
```

Comment: Actually I'm sure it will always return `true`, but never `false`, the code in your click handler is executed long after `return true;` was executed. You need to return a `Promise` that completes with `true` or `false` depending on what click handler is clicked.

Comment: Actually I used Promise as well, which asks for confirmation even when I submit the form & also when there is no change in the form values. That's the reason I combined these codes with observable. I've added my code with Promise after edit. Any suggests !!

Comment: I'm not able to see how form values and `Promise` are related from your code.

Comment: But I can't help you with something I don't know anything about. Your question doesn't provide any information about a form or changes and how they might be related to your question.

Comment: I tried putting promise in "if" condition but that didn't help. That's the area where I need help. If you could help.

Comment: Please add the code to your question. It's pointless to discuss things I can't see.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I've updated the code with html form as well for you, please refer & suggest.

Comment: If you comment the whole modal code and `return true;` as first line in `canActivate, does the route change work as expected?

Comment: When I make the above changes, the modal doesn't show-up even when I make changes in the form field. That may be because I'm returning only `true` when the function gets called.

Comment: That was the intention. I want to know if the routing issue is related to the modal at all or if there is an issue with your routing configuration. My question was, does the routing work as expected (like if the confirm button  had been pressed) when you just `return true;`?

Comment: I commented the default `return true` statement. After that the respective buttons do log true & false when I click on them but the route stays on the same page. May be the click events are returning the values after the canDeactivate has finished execution. How can we make the function wait till either of the click events returns something ?

Comment: This is the exact opposite of what I asked for. I want to know if routing works when no dialog is used and you just indicate "confirm" was clicked by `return true;` without any other code in `canActivate()`

Comment: Yes, the page routes without any confirmation when I keep only return true in canDeactivate function.

Comment: Then I don't see why your code using the Promise shouldn't work the same. If you can create a reproduction in https://stackblitz.com/ I can investigate further, but without that I don't think I'm able to make suggestion. I don't see anything wrong.